# Reorganize data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in R which is as follows:

```
A <- c(7,2,7)
B <- c(1,8,4)
C <- c(9,4,3)
Category <- c("A","B","C")

df <- data.frame(Category, A, B, C)
```

The data frame looks like this:

```
  Category | A | B | C
 -----------------------
     A       7   1   9
     B       2   8   4
     C       7   4   3
```

How can I reorganize the data frame in r to get the below output?

```
Category | Category | Value
---------------------------
    A         A         7    
    A         B         1
    A         C         9
    B         A         2
    B         B         8
    B         C         4
    C         A         7
    C         B         4
    C         C         3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can do this is using the `tidverse` by gathering the data and then after it is gathered renaming a column to have two columns with the same name.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  gather(Category2, Value, -Category) %>% 
  arrange(Category, Category2) %>% 
  rename(Category=Category2)
```

Comment: Thank you. Although I liked your approach as well as akrun's approach, I just decided to mark your answer as the accepted solution. However, akrun's solution is equally good.

Answer (score 2):

An easier option would be to transpose the dataset without the first column, then change the column name to 'Category' values and convert to `data.frame` after giving the `table` attribute

```
as.data.frame.table(`colnames<-`(t(df[-1]), df$Category))[c(2, 1, 3)]
#   Var2 Var1 Freq
#1    A    A    7
#2    A    B    1
#3    A    C    9
#4    B    A    2
#5    B    B    8
#6    B    C    4
#7    C    A    7
#8    C    B    4
#9    C    C    3
```

---

Or using `melt` after converting to `matrix`

```
library(reshape)
melt(as.matrix(`row.names<-`(df[-1], df$Category)))
```